# Getting Error: http: read on closed response body from Transaction Processor function in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I've a fabric network running with a simple BNA. This BNA defines two types of participants viz. Corporate and Person. Here, each Person has a relationship with the corporate as shown below (cto file):

```
participant Corporate identified by corporateId {
    o String corporateId
    o String corporateName
}
participant Person identified by personId {
    o String personId
    --> Corporate corporate
}
```

What I'm trying to do:

1. Create a Corporate using Transaction Processor Function: Success
2. Create a Person using Transaction Processor Function: Failure

Following is the snippet from transaction processor function for #2:

```
let corporateIdExpected = personDetails.corporate;

if(corporateIdExpected && corporateIdExpected != '') {
    let corporateRetrieved = await query("GetCorporateByCorporateId", {corporateId: corporateIdExpected});
    if(!corporateRetrieved || corporateRetrieved == '') {
        throw new Error("Corporate details not valid. Please check if your corporate is present on the network.");
    }
}
```

Snippet from my queries.qry:

```
query GetCorporateByCorporateId {
  description: "Returns all corporates in the registry"
  statement:  
      SELECT  org.samplenetwork.participants.Corporate
          WHERE (corporateId == _$corporateId)
}
```

So, I get the following error when I try the #2:

> Error: 2 UNKNOWN: error executing chaincode: transaction returned with failure: Error: Error: http: read on closed response body

However, when I try to execute the query directly from the swagger, it runs successfully.

I'm using:

Hyperledger Fabric: 1.1
Hyperledger Composer: 0.19.8

Am I missing out any checks or steps for this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for item 2 - you don't really need to execute a named query each time.

You can do the equivalent check ("does he exist already?") as follows (where `trxn` below is the transaction object defined in your transaction definition etc):

```
const personRegistry = await getParticipantRegistry('org.acme.example.Person');
console.log("The person identifier to check is " + trxn.corporate.getIdentifier() ) 

const exists = await personRegistry.exists(trxn.corporate.getIdentifier() ) ;

console.log("exists is set to " + exists); // boolean

if (exists)
        console.log("he exists") 
else
        console.log("he doesn't exist");
```

Comment: I tried this way. It kept throwing: " Error: object type or attribute not a non-zero length string". I've made sure I supply correct value to this one. Also, I believe I'll need to use named query at many places. I rewrote the function and now the query in the TP resulted in: "Use Serializer.toJSON() to convert Resource to JSON object". I used it and then it resulted in "Serializer not defined/referenced". Also tried to use "getSerializer()". It too resulted in "Use Serializer.toJSON()...

Comment: right, I've only seen a snippet of your code. It seems other parts of your function, are not working (sounds like you're trying to treat a Resource as a JSON object). If you want to post that as a separate question, feel free, with exactly what you want to do (ie what should my result look like). The suggestion above, is based on what was perceived you're trying to achieve forn the initial question (ie check for existence of something).

Comment: Perfect. Got it working with the way you mentioned. Actually, I'm from Java background so there's a little learning curve for JavaScript semantics and syntax. Also, I believe I was using query the wrong away. However, I'll try that and update this thread as well: https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/4246