# Hyperledger transaction Permission to participant based on some 3rd resource

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I was working on some permission logic for Hyperledger , When need arise for a condition where i need to use 3 resources in permission.acl condition.

To Brief about scenario Let us suppose Resource Transaction is t for which Read Permission needs to be given, Participant is P Who needs to read transaction t.

Now Transaction t contains an identifier name for Asset A  . 
So I want to make a condition like if Asset A where Identifier(name) is equal to to the transaction T name , compares the Asset A registrar(This will hold participant name)  with the Participant P Identifier. And If comparison is successful then give read permission of Resource(Transaction T) to Participant P.

Eg Snippet.

```
Asset ABC identified by name{
    o String name;
    --> Company registrar; (Company is type of participant)

}

Transaction CreateABC{
     o String name;
}
```

So Participant P of type company should have permission to Read Transaction CreateABC if the Asset containing createABC.name has registar equal to P.getIdenitifer();

I have read that We can  create separate functions in js file and call that from permission.acl but i am not yet able to fulfill this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. An example of using 3 resources would be something like (example):

// first, access to invoke the transaction resource itself

```
rule Transaction_access {
    description: "Can generate transaction"
    participant: "org.acme.account.AccountTrader"
    operation: CREATE
    resource: "org.acme.account.TransferAmount"
    action: ALLOW
}
```

// next, the (example) dynamic ACL rule that evaluates between who the transaction is being done

```
rule BiTrade_betweenTraders_only {
    description: "Only Allow Updatee between Transferor/Transferee via named transaction"
    participant(p): "org.acme.account.AccountTrader"
    operation: ALL
    resource(v): "org.acme.account.BankAccount"
    transaction(tx): "org.acme.account.TransferAmount"
  condition: ( p.getIdentifier() === v.owner.getIdentifier()  && v.getIdentifier() === tx.targetAccount.getIdentifier() )
    action: ALLOW
}
```

UPDATED with item 2:

2. An example of giving access to a transaction resource, based on an Asset ownership by a participant (both derived from the transaction object) might be:

```
rule my_restricted_Transaction_access {
           description: "as per description above"
           participant(p): "org.acme.account.AccountTrader"
           operation: CREATE
           resource(v): "org.acme.account.TransferAmount"
           condition: ( p.getIdentifier() === v.account.owner.getIdentifier() )
           action: ALLOW
}
```

where `TransferAmount` might be defined as:

```
transaction TransferAmount {
   --> Account account   // asset
}
```

and `account` has an `--> owner` field pointing back to AccountTrader ( the participant, in my original example - etc etc) - bear in mind, your ACLs would have to allow the participant to have access to the relevant asset and asset owner target resource too.

obviously this is a simple example - but you can define your function (to do the equivalent check, for your model) in the `condition` section. If you've added the JS script to your BNA under `/lib` (and upgraded the business network on Fabric to take effect) - you then just have to worry about whether your function name is what you called it (again, the links I sent you should provide a clear example of it in use).

3. Calling a function as part of your ACL condition is straightforward - you can see an example of this in this github test file -> the function (JS) is here https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/blob/master/packages/composer-tests-functional/systest/data/accesscontrols.js#L23 and the corresponding (calling) ACL ruleset is here -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/blob/master/packages/composer-tests-functional/systest/data/accesscontrols.acl#L124

UPDATED item 3:

eg in your permissions.acl file a rule like:

```
rule rule_func_condition {
    description: "Allow all participants access to all resources"
    participant(p): "org.acme.account.AccountTrader"
    operation: CREATE
    resource(a): "org.example.account.TransferAmount"
    condition: (testOwnership(a, p))
    action: ALLOW
}
```

in your functions.js (or whatever) in the `/lib` folder (or you can have it your existing logic.js if you prefer, however you want to do it):

```
/**
 * Test that the specified asset is owned by the specified participant.
 * @param {Resource} asset The asset.
 * @param {Resource} participant The participant.
 * @return {boolean} True if yes, false if no.
 */
function testOwnership(asset, participant) {
    return asset.owner.getIdentifier() === participant.getIdentifier();
}
```

where `asset` and `participant` objects are passed into this particular function example.

Comment: Thanks for quick response paul, The example of Dynamic ACL that you have provided is giving access of a resource(ASSET) to a participant based on some condition in transactions. However What i want to achieve is a bit different , I want to give access to transaction based on an Asset ownership with participant and this Asset need to be derived from transaction data. I will try to do it using the function calling and will post updates here.

Comment: I tried with the approach you have mentioned , but some how permission.acl is not able to read the function in my javascript file , Do I need to include javascript  file name in the permission.acl so that function can be found.
Error: {"log":"2018-09-11T05:36:49.439Z [c6c42404] DEBUG    :CompiledAclBundle        :execute()                 Function threw error {\"stack\":[\"{ReferenceError}checkPermission is not defined ReferenceError: checkPermission is not defined\",\

Comment: I've added an item 2 to my answer as an example. See my comments above.

Comment: I understood the condition you are mentioning and i have already been using such conditions for some of transactions but in this case Transaction itself is creating the Asset so relationship to asset can't be passed in the transaction. For doing it using function i have defined the function in a files name accesscontrols.js and added this file inside the scripts folder and called it in permissiom.acl, but i always get same error that function is not defined. The links you have provided give good example om how to write these functions but doesn't explain where this js should be kept and named.

Comment: I am sure that file is getting compiled while i am creating and deploying the BNA because any syntax error in the the js file is causing my BNA creation to get failed , SO i am sure that BNA contains the newly created function but somehow it appears that Permissions.acl is not able to locate this API. Now i am not sure whether it could be some namespace issue or some naming convention that i am not following. MY acl file is Permissions.acl at root of bna directory. and i have tried to add the js file with function logic in same directory inside lib/ or inside scripts/ folder as you mentioned.

Comment: hi, think it should be `/lib` not `/scripts` FYI. I've added an example, that works (calls the function, and filters on the owner in the ACL). Now you just need to work out, what data you want to provide to the test itself. Good luck!

Comment: Actually I have already tried putting function in logic.js and as a seprate file in lib/ directory , Could it be possible that i am passing  transaction,participant in function instead of Asset as you have shown. As I want to control permission of a transaction. Meanwhile I will try a simple function as you have shown to check permission over an Asset.

Comment: You should have one rule that allows all (relevant participants) to READ the 'transaction' - so that your owner param can be read, otherwise its pointless. You would have another rule below it,  that allows 'CREATE' - only - ie based on the condition (name = matching participant identifer). That would be rule two.  I don't really know why your function isn't working, you have to check (you can do so in online playground FYI) if you're calling it correctly etc.

Comment: Well It worked this time , I had some syntax error. This time I have added function in logic.js and it worked. Thanks for the help. However As of now I am getting Error inside function saying "The run-time API is not available". I Was trying to access the Asset registry so it appears I can't use those API's in the function called by ACL .

Comment: your helper function, doesn't need to be a transaction function - you can pass it objects (or values) from your transaction function and compare the values - it can be a simple as that which I posted. Another example here -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/blob/master/packages/fund-clearing-network/permissions.acl (and under `/lib`) . An example for checking if something exists is here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52223280/getting-error-http-read-on-closed-response-body-from-transaction-processor-fun/52223764#52223764